# rspec-rails post single param with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have `FavoritesController#create` which only accepts one input param, `doctor_id`, from post request.

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
    @favorite = Favorite.new(favorite_params)
    @favorite.patient_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @favorite.save!
        format.js
      else
        format.json { render json: @favorite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def favorite_params
      params.require(:favorite).permit(:doctor_id)
    end
end
```

And I got 2 examples to test it

```
describe FavoritesController do

  login_patient

  def valid_attributes
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:favorite, doctor_id: rand(1..1000))
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Favorite" do
        expect {
          post :create, favorite: valid_attributes, format: :js
        }.to change(Favorite, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "redirects to the created favorite" do
        post :create, favorite: valid_attributes, format: :js
        response.should render_template :create
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I got error on the parameter

```
1) FavoritesController POST create with valid params creates a new Favorite
   Failure/Error: post :create, favorite: valid_attributes, format: :js
   ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
     Validation failed: Doctor can't be empty
   # ./app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:18:in `block in create'
   # ./app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:17:in `create'
   # ./spec/controllers/favorite_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/controllers/favorite_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) FavoritesController POST create with valid params redirects to the created favorite
   Failure/Error: post :create, favorite: valid_attributes, format: :js
   ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
     Validation failed: Doctor can't be empty
   # ./app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:18:in `block in create'
   # ./app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:17:in `create'
   # ./spec/controllers/favorite_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I believe I've given valid params as defined in controller, but due to the validation it looks like it is asking for `@doctor` instead of `doctor_id`

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient

  validates :doctor, :patient, presence: true
end
```

and here is my Factory

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name = Faker::Name.name
    name name
    address Faker::Address.street_address
    phone Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    password Faker::Internet.password
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{name.split.join.downcase}_#{n}@example.com" }
  end

  factory :doctor, class: Doctor, parent: :user do
    roles [0,1]
    field
  end

  factory :patient, class: Patient, parent: :user do
    roles [1]
  end
end
```

any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient

  validates :doctor, :patient, presence: true
end
```

As `Favorite is belongs to doctor` when you are trying to create Favorite Doctor should exist before.

You are getting this error due to as your trying to create `favorite` it looks for the presence `doctor` with id that you passed in DB and you passed `random number` as `doctor_id` so it `fails validation` as `doctor record does not exist`.

You have to `create doctor record` first and pass the `id` of that doctor record to `doctor_id` of favorite attributes.

option 1:-

```
  def valid_attributes
    doctor = FactoryGirl.create(:doctor)
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:favorite, doctor_id: doctor.id)
  end
```

option 2 :-

```
  def valid_attributes(doctor_id)
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:favorite, doctor_id: doctor_id)
  end

  let(:doctor) { create(:doctor) }
  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Favorite" do
        expect {
          post :create, favorite: valid_attributes(doctor.id), format: :js
        }.to change(Favorite, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Awesome! That is a clear explanation, I have no clue if the random id was the problem. Many thanks!